# C# 4.0/EF - Server-generated keys and server-generated values are not supported by SQL Server Compact

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-4

I have just moved one of my projects into VS2010/fx4.0 and am using a SQL CE database as the backing store.  Since moving it to this version of .NET I am now getting this error:

> Server-generated keys and server-generated values are not supported by SQL Server Compact.

My table ***was*** defined with a PK of UserName (string) & DoorOpen (datetime) as SQLCE **required** there be a PK on every table in fx3.5.  Now that I am in fx4.0 I am stumped.  I've googled for this and every answer I found was:

> SQLCE does not support auto-generating values (which I am most certainly not needing) so put a GUID ID on there and populate it from code.

I tried this approach and I am still getting the same error!

SQLCE:

```
CREATE TABLE [ImportDoorAccesses] (
    [RawData] nvarchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [DoorOpen] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [UserName] nvarchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [CardNumber] bigint  NOT NULL,
    [Door] nvarchar(4000)  NOT NULL,
    [Imported] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [ID] uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL -- new column
);

ALTER TABLE [ImportDoorAccesses]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ImportDoorAccesses]
    PRIMARY KEY ([ID] );
```

The constraint used to be:

```
ALTER TABLE [ImportDoorAccesses]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ImportDoorAccesses]
    PRIMARY KEY ([DoorOpen],[UserName]);
```

CODE:

```
foreach (dto.DoorAudit newDoorAudit in dataTransferObject)
{
    if (newDoorAudit.DoInsert)
    {
        myEntities.AddToImportDoorAccesses(new ImportDoorAccess
        {
            CardNumber = newDoorAudit.CardNumber,
            Door = newDoorAudit.Door,
            DoorOpen = newDoorAudit.DoorOpen,
            Imported = newDoorAudit.Imported,
            RawData = newDoorAudit.RawData,
            UserName = newDoorAudit.UserName,
            ID = Guid.NewGuid()  // LOOK - HERE IT IS AS SUGGESTED!
        });
    }
}
myEntities.SaveChanges();
```

So, now what?  Is this a bug in EF4?  Am I doing something wrong?

TIA

---

NOTE:

Going through the EDMX file (right-click, open with, XML) I found that one of my date columns was set with *StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"*.

```
  <EntityType Name="ImportDoorAccesses">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="RawData" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
    <Property Name="DoorOpen" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="UserName" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
    <Property Name="CardNumber" Type="bigint" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="Door" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="Imported" Type="datetime" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="ID" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
  </EntityType>
```

I then switched back to the pretty model view and clicked on every single column in my database to make sure this was **NOT** set.  A PITA for sure.  Looks like a perfect little tool/add-in needs to be created...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to check is the EDMX file and make sure this property/column doesn't have a StoreGeneratedPattern of identity in there.