# Error on use of SQL Server Compact and EF

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I am using the VS2010 + SQL Server CE 3.5 + EF + Framework 4.

I have no problem in reading data from SQL Server CE.

But on inserting data with this code:

```
EFConn.SaveChanges();
```

I get an error:

> Error: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner
>   exception for details.

please help me...

Error detail :

> System.Data.UpdateException was unhandled
>
> Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner
>   exception for details.
>
> Source=System.Data.Entity
>
> InnerException: System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException
>
> Message=An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Source=System.Data.Entity
>
> InnerException: System.NotSupportedException
>
> Message=Server-generated keys and server-generated values are not supported by SQL Server Compact.
>
> Source=System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity

Comment: Can you give some of the details?

Comment: are you using a table with IDENTITY(1, 1)?

Comment: yes. i using a table with IDENTITY(1, 1)...

Comment: You may want to take a look at [SqlCe and EntityFramework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632511/syntax-for-insert-and-update-with-sqlce-and-entityframework)

Answer (score 0):

1. SQL CE version 4.0 fixed this problem with its Entity Framework provider. 
   You can download it from  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876
2. If you don't want to change SQL CE, you can try to change the field type to uniqueidentifier. You can do this [Server-generated keys and server-generated values are not supported by SQL Server Compact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648449/server-generated-keys-and-server-generated-values-are-not-supported-by-sql-serve)

Hope this helps