# How to add Object in SQL Server Compact 3.5 using Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce-3.5

I'm beginner to Entity Framework. I have VS 2010 installed. I'm able to access data from  a SQL Server Compact 3.5 `.sdf` file, but I'm not able to write using Entity Framework.

This is the code I'm using:

```
db.Models.AddObject(new Model() {Name="myname"});
db.SaveChanges();
```

and I am not able to add any new data objects to SQL Server Compact 3.5 using Entity Framework - why is that and how to deal with it?

Suggestions and guidelines are highly appreciated

Comment: Check the bin/debug folder for a copy of the database, and install the   SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in for editing/viewing data

Comment: Thanks ErikEJ,
I mean editing SQL Server Compact data using Entity Framework 4.0? I installed SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in able to edit existing object data  but add new object via 
db.Models.AddObject(new Model() {Name="myname"}); 
db.SaveChanges();

is still creating error.

Comment: Pls update your question with the error message, you do not mention anything about errors...!

Comment: @ErikEJ, 
InnerException: System.Data.UpdateException
       HResult=-2146233087
       Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       Source=System.Data.Entity
       StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
            at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
            at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
            at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()

Comment: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmProperty]' to type 'System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCollection`1[System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmProperty]'."

Comment: Is that the inner exception?

Comment: @ErikEJ, Yeah this is inner exception. Now I could access existing database at SQL Server Compact 3.5 and even modify or delete it using Entity framework. 

There is this error on creating new object at save to SQL Server Compact 3.5 using Entity frame work. Even allocating Id manually didn't help. Could u suggest any other option to create new object and pass to database beside 

db.Models.AddObject(new Model() {Id= 7, Name="myname"});
db.SaveChanges(); //if I comment SaveChanges() program runs but no change in database

Thanking you

Comment: Thanks I shorted out the problem:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734424/c-sharp-4-0-ef-server-generated-keys-and-server-generated-values-are-not-suppo

Comment: Ok, this issue is fixed in EF 6